# Simultaneous 100% wide divs

Tags: html, horizontal-scrolling, alignment

I'm having trouble making a page that has multiple divs aligned horizontally, each sized 100% by 100%, so the page scrolls horizontally.

The ultimate goal will be a horizontal smooth scroll between the divs.  I'm not entirely sure where to start.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please post what you have?

Answer (score 0):

What about something similar to this? Just adjust the height and width of each based on the number of horizontal divs.

[JFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/V89Je/1/)

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    width: 200%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

#firstDiv {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

#secondDiv {
    float:  left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="firstDiv"></div>
<div id="secondDiv"></div>
```

Comment: This works, but it messes with another div that's set position:absolute.  Instead of staying in the fixed place it stays within the first div (the red one, in the example code above.)

Comment: What if you changed the position of the absolute div to fixed?